# How do I use a new 27" iMac as an external PC monitor with full 2560x1440 resolution?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

The new 27" iMac has a nice LED backlit display that runs at 2560x1440 and supports *input* from external DisplayPort sources.

In addition to playing with the Mac I'm interested in getting this to replace my old second monitor with something closer to my primary display, which is a 30" Dell running at 2560x1600.

Is this possible?

My PC has two dual-link DVI ports so I have no concerns there, but it doesn't look like Apple's adapter (http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A) is intended for PC-to-iMac use but the other way around. Searching around on the web I see plausible adapters, along with suggestions they may not support resolutions over 1920x1600.

-- **UPDATE** --

So I bought the 27" iMac and there's good news and bad news...

The good news is that this isn't a hairbrained idea, as long as you use a newer video card that offers DisplayPort output and buy a DisplayPort to Mini Displayport cable for about $20.

The bad news is that some video cards still do not work. When I failed to get this working with an ATI 5770 I asked about it over on the [AMD forums](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=279&threadid=121507&enterthread=y) and a helpful person was having the same problem. He then tried an ATI 4890 and got it working easily.

Answer (score 2):

It only has a Display port connector on it, so you will need an adapter... unless you have one of the rare computers that has it.

[Just found this](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-DVI-to-Mini-DisplayPort-Converter-p-17859.html), however I cannot recommend it over any other brand.

[image]

Comment: There are other companies making them as well.  It should be highlighted that DVI to DisplayPort is not a simple adapter cable.  There is a difference in the actual signal.

Comment: yeah, that was one of the plausible ones i found that doesn't go over 1920x1600. and at that price i'd be better off buying a new video card. ouch!

Comment: so... i ended up buying the 27" iMac anyway. in a month or two, as the budget permits, i'll get a video card that supports DisplayPort and see how it works out.